# Can't remove a particular part of an object

Tags: edit-mode

I have a model of a bulk carrier (ore/gravel) which includes an excavator which I am trying to remove. I select the object then go to edit mode and 'lasso' the excavator then 'hit' Delete and select delete vertices. I do this until I am satisfied I have removed all the vertices yet there remains what appears to be the glass in the cabin which cannot be selected.
What do I need to do to remove this.  Refer following images the first showing the model complete with the excavator and the second after I have deleted all the vertices for that excavator and showing what appears to be the glass from the cabin which cannot be selected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's not part of the same object, it's another object?

Comment: What @moonboots says. Look at the mesh icon (the orange triangle) in the outliner, there is a little `2` indicating `node0` has two meshes under it. Expand `node0` and you should see the glass mesh.

Comment: @taiyo Exactly, I was just about to comment on this. Since the glass cabin does not show any black outlined edges or center dots of faces like the other parts in _Edit Mode_ it is most likely (or I would say certainly) a separate object. If this was rendered preview, another possibility would have been that the faces of the cabin are hidden in _Edit Mode_, this way they would get rendered but not show any outline markings for vertices, edges or faces. But it's _Material Preview_, so it should simply be a separate object.

Comment: STUPID me.  I just thought of that before reading your replies. That is EXACTLY what it is and can be deleted on object mode.    Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the same object, it's another object, switch back to *Object* mode, select this object and remove.

Comment: Yes that is the answer and what I discovered before I read these posts. My brain is still in 'low range' coming to terms with my current emotions.